# Cordova / SQLite: rowid undefined

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, rowid

With SQLite and Cordova on an Android device.

I have a database containing a table with some fields.

None of the fields is a primary key so the records have a default `rowid` generated by SQLite.

Here is a screenshot of the table in Chrome debugger:[image: table in Chrome debugger]

I'm trying to access that `rowid` (I spare you all the database code and focus on the query):

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ServicesRondes', [], function(tx, res) {
    console.log(res.rows.length); // shows 5
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(res.rows.item(i).time); // shows the time record
            console.log(res.rows.item(i).rowid); // shows undefined
        }
    }               
}
```

So the problem is that the `rowid` is `undefined` in the logs.

I've found only one link with a guy answering his own question: https://forum.qt.io/topic/53217/solved-how-to-access-sqlite-rowid

As you can see, he made a query with `rowid` to solve his problem.

But it's not really what I want (I want to select all) and furthermore, I don't get why it works this way and not the other way.

Of course I could create my own autoincremented primary key field but I'd like to avoid it and this is not my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT *` returns all columns that you have declared in the table definition.

If you want the `rowid` column to show up with `*`, you have to include it there:

```
CREATE TABLE ServicesRondes (
    rowid     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    userUuid  UUID,
    secteurId UUID,
    time      TIMESTAMP,
    [...]
);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know that thing about declared columns. So maybe in the end doing my own autoincremented column would be better than selecting every column to include the rowid one.